# How can I improve a classification algorithm for dogs and cats?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, scikit-learn, stochastic-gradient-descent

The following code is a ML algorithm trained to classify between dogs and cats, the database is composed by 25000 images (evenly split) and can be obtained at this [Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54765) (if you click it will automatically download it!)

Half of the code is basically the tutorial that sentdex has created ([Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-3vuBynnOE)) while the "prediction part" is the application of the SGD classifier from SK Learn. When trying to cross-validate, results are quite poor.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
from PIL import Image
from scipy import ndimage, misc

DATADIR = r"C:\Users\robda\Desktop\Petimages"     #my path to the folders
CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]

training_data = []    #function to transform images in arrays

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:  # do dogs and cats

        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  
        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):  
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) 
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])  
            except Exception as e:  
                pass

create_training_data()

import random
random.shuffle(training_data)
X = []
y = []
for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y = np.array(y)

X2 = X.reshape(24946,10000)
y2 = y.ravel()
X_training = X2[:20000]
y_training = y2[:20000]
X_test = X2[20001:]
y_test = y2[20001:]

from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier( random_state =42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_training, y_training)

some_animal=X_test[1900]
some_animal_image = some_animal.reshape( 100, 100)
plt.imshow(some_animal_image, cmap="binary")
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

prediction = sgd_clf.predict([some_animal])   #prediction
print(f"prediction: {prediction }")

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score    #cross validation score is around 50%
print(f"accuracy: {cross_val_score(sgd_clf, X_training, y_training, cv=3,scoring='accuracy')}")
```

Could you please help me understand what can be improved and what has to be changed? Moreover, do you recommend using SK learn for machine learning? Thanks

Comment: You didn't include your links

Comment: My bad, links have been added

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to classify images and using a linear classifier without using any sort of image descriptor or feature extractor. Do not use this approach for any image classification problem. You can try following approaches:

1. With images, your first choice of model should be convolutional neural networks since they can extract abstract features from the images and then you can use a fully connected layer as a classifier.
2. If you do not want to use CNN, then you can either use a descriptor like Histogram of gradients to encode the features of images and then use a linear/non-linear classifier like SVM to classify the images to improve your accuracy.